# Creating a word generator with yield

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

I'm trying to create a word generator using `yield` and write each item to a file, however in the file output, when I write to the file, I get something along the lines of:

```
         C   sh   t  d t d t d d � d d � �< } x2 t | j �  � |  k r] | j t t �  � � q, WWd  QXd  S(   Ns   bfDict-t
   use_stringt   lengthi
   s   .txts   a+(   t   openR   t   Truet   lent      readlinest   writet   nextR   (   t     max_wordst   lib(    (    s[   C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\python\HashKing\lib\attacks\bruteforce\bf_attack.pyt   create_wordlist   s    )(
   t   ost   stringt   randomR   t   lib.algorithms.hashing_algst   lib.settingsR   t   FalseR   R   (    (    (    s[   C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\python\HashKing\lib\attacks\bruteforce\bf_attack.pyt   <module>   s   
l2\colorlog\colorlog\logging.pyt   wrapper   s    
(   t      functoolst   wraps(   R   R   (    (   R   sT   c:\users\z-perk~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-build-rtaul2\colorlog\colorlog\logging.pyt   ensure_configured   s    (   t   __doc__t
   __future__R    R   R   t   colorlog.colorlogR   R   R   R   R   t       getLoggert   debugt   infot   warningt   errort   criticalt   logt      exceptiont
   StreamHandler(    (    (    sT   c:\users\z-perk~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-build-rtaul2\colorlog\colorlog\logging.pyt   <module>   s"           
            s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR   g   s            t   _COORDc           B   s    e  Z d  e f d e f g Z RS(   t   Xt   Y(   R   R     R   R   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR   n   s      t   POINTc           B   s    e  Z d  e f d e f g Z RS(   t   xt   y(   R   R      R   R   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR   r   s      t   SIZEc           B   s    e  Z d  e f d e f g Z RS(   t   cxt   cy(   R   R     R   R   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR   w   s      c         C   s   |  | d >| d >S(   Ni   i   (    (   t   redt   greent   blue(    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyt   RGB|   s    t   FILETIMEc           B   s    e  Z d  e f d e f g Z RS(   t
   dwLowDateTimet   dwHighDateTime(   R   R    t   DWORDR   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR%      s     t   MSGc           B   sD   e  Z d  e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f g Z RS(   t   hWndt   messaget   wParamt   lParamt   timet   pt(     R   R       t   HWNDt   c_uintt   WPARAMt   LPARAMR(   R   R   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR)   �   s                      i  t   WIN32_FIND_DATAAc           B   sp   e  Z d  e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e e f d  e d
 f g
 Z RS(   t   dwFileAttributest   ftCreationTimet   ftLastAccessTimet   ftLastWriteTimet
   nFileSizeHight   nFileSizeLowt   dwReserved0t   dwReserved1t    cFileNamet   cAlternateFileNamei   (   R   R    R(   R%   t   c_chart   MAX_PATHR   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyR4   �   s                                 
t   WIN32_FIND_DATAWc           B   sp   e  Z d  e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e f d e e f d     e d
 f g
 Z RS(   R5   R6   R7   R8   R9   R:   R;   R<   R=   R>   i   (   R   R       R(   R%   t   c_wcharR@   R   (    (    (    s"   C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.pyRA   �   s                                   
t   ATOMt   BOOLt   BOOLEANt   BYTEt   CO
```

My generator looks like this:

```
import itertools

def word_generator(length_min=6, length_max=12, perms=False):
    chrs = 'abc'
    for n in range(length_min, length_max + 1):
        for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=n):
            yield ''.join(xs)


def create_wordlist(max_words=100000):
    with open("words.txt", "a+") as lib:
        while len(lib.readlines()) <= max_words:
                lib.write(next(word_generator()))
```

What is causing the strange output in this file?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess the problem, but from your codes here are the possibilities:

The encoding of your text editor or shell could be set to an encoding that's incompatible with ASCII encoding.

You should check the encoding of your text editor if you happened to open your file with a text editor. Or check the encoding of the shell you're using if you happened to read the file in a shell.

If you're using Python 2.X and if you didn't change the default encoding in your system, then your strings will be written to the file as ASCII. In 3.X this is slightly different, for `open` you can specify the encoding explicitly: `open('...', '+a', encoding='utf-8')`. So try to specify the encoding of your files in 3.X in `open` and see what happens if you you're using 3.X.

Answer (score 0):

First, when I ran you code, I got nothing like what you posted. The program went into an infinite loop of putting 'a' chars in the 'words.txt' file. I don't know what caused the wierd string that you posted, but I could see 3 problems on your code.

Your `word_generator` seems ok. The problems are in `create_wordlist`.

**Problem 1:**
This pice of code `next(word_generator())` instead of getting the next element of an existing sequence, creates a new sequence and then takes it's next element. Sice it's a brand new sequence, its next element is its first element, 'aaaaaa' in this case.
Istead of creating a new sequance every iteration, you should create it only once an then call `next` repeatedly on it. Example shown below:

```
wgen = word_generator()
wilhe some_condition:
    lib.write(next(wgen))
```

**Problem 2:**
Since you try to count words by the size of `lib.readlines()`, I believe you expect the file to have a single word per line, but that is not the line `lib.write(next(word_generator()))` does, for no '\n' char is written. You should add the line `lib.write('\n')` to the code or append a '\n' char to the word if you want a single word per line:

```
wgen = word_generator()
wilhe some_condition:
    lib.write(next(wgen) + '\n')
```

**Problem 3:**
When you open "words.txt" in "a+" mode, the stream position is set to the end of the file, with subsequent calls to `lib.write()` maintaining this behavior. Bacause of that, calls to `lib.readlines()` will read lines starting from the end of file, thus always returning an empty array of size zero. This makes your `while len(lib.readlines()) <= max_words:` an infinite loop.

To fix it, you should either find another way of counting the words in the file or use `lib.seek(0, 0)` to travel to the begining of the file before calling `lib.readlines()` ([See doc on `seek`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))

Since reading all lines of the file every iteration is terribly inneficient, I took another approach in the solution below. I counted the initial amount of lines only once:

```
def create_wordlist(max_words=100000):
    with open("words.txt", "a+") as lib:
        wgen = word_generator() # Creates the sequence of words

        lib.seek(0, 0)  # Goes to the begining of the file
        line_count = len(lib.readlines())   # Counts how many lines the file has

        # lib.readlines() set the stream position to the end,
        #   so now following 'lib.write()' calls will write to the end as expected.

        # For each missing line before reaching 'max_words' lines
        for i in range(line_count, max_words):
            lib.write(next(wgen) + '\n')    # Writes the next word in the sequence
```